# Erro na hora do build do IONIC e Cordova

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova

Bom, procurei em todos os lugares e não consegui achar a solução. Dou o comando "ionic cordova build android" e aparece esse erro abaixo.

[image: Erro ao dar build]

Levando que já criei o "plataform" porem não acho as pastas "Outputs"

Comment: Pelo que vi, vc não declarou as variáveis de ambiente do ANDROID, o que não tem nada com o ionic, e sim com o processo de compilação do Android.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião, de acordo com o que ta descrito no erro, ele não encontrou o arquivo `android`, tente 
iniciar o comando na pasta onde está seus arquivos. Para mais informações sobre o erro rode o camando escrito lá: `--verbose`. Outra coisa é que para mexer no ionic você tem que ter o nodeJS https://nodejs.org/en/ , (não sei se sempre mais pelo menos quando eu ultilizei precisava). Para mais informações sobre o ionic use o seu site: https://ionicframework.com/getting-started#cli